# Move execution point in Xcode/lldb

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

Is there a way to set the execution point while debugging Xcode/lldb?  To be more specific, after hitting a breakpoint, moving the execution point manually to another line of code?

Answer (score 15):

If you're looking at moving it up or down with in a method you can click and drag the green arrow to a specific point. so if you want to back up a line before the breakpoint. click on the green arrow that is produced and drag it up. If you hit run you'll hit your breakpoint again

Comment: In Xcode 9.1, the green arrow has been changed to a green hamburger, and moved to the right margin.

Comment: This has got to be the coolest least-known feature of Xcode debugging.

Comment: @JerryKrinock your comment is more "up to date" then the most up-voted reply.

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 6, you can use `j lineNumber` - see documentation below:

```
(lldb) help j
     Sets the program counter to a new address.  This command takes 'raw' input
     (no need to quote stuff).

Syntax: _regexp-jump [<line>]
_regexp-jump [<+-lineoffset>]
_regexp-jump [<file>:<line>]
_regexp-jump [*<addr>]


'j' is an abbreviation for '_regexp-jump'
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the great things about lldb is that it's easy to extend it with a little bit of python scripting.  For instance, I threw together a new `jump` command without much trouble:

```
import lldb

def jump(debugger, command, result, dict):
  """Usage: jump LINE-NUMBER
Jump to a specific source line of the current frame.
Finds the first code address for a given source line, sets the pc to that value.  
Jumping across any allocation/deallocation boundaries (may not be obvious with ARC!), or with optimized code, quickly leads to undefined/crashy behavior. """

  if lldb.frame and len(command) >= 1:
    line_num = int(command)
    context = lldb.frame.GetSymbolContext (lldb.eSymbolContextEverything)
    if context and context.GetCompileUnit():
      compile_unit = context.GetCompileUnit()
      line_index = compile_unit.FindLineEntryIndex (0, line_num, compile_unit.GetFileSpec(), False)
      target_line = compile_unit.GetLineEntryAtIndex (line_index)
      if target_line and target_line.GetStartAddress().IsValid():
        addr = target_line.GetStartAddress().GetLoadAddress (lldb.target)
        if addr != lldb.LLDB_INVALID_ADDRESS:
          if lldb.frame.SetPC (addr):
            print "PC has been set to 0x%x for %s:%d" % (addr, target_line.GetFileSpec().GetFilename(), target_line.GetLine())

def __lldb_init_module (debugger, dict):
  debugger.HandleCommand('command script add -f %s.jump jump' % __name__)
```

I put this in a directory where I keep Python commands for lldb, `~/lldb/`, and I load it in my `~/.lldbinit` file with

```
command script import ~/lldb/jump.py
```

and now I have a command `jump` (`j` works) which will jump to a given line number.  e.g.

```
(lldb) j 5
PC has been set to 0x100000f0f for a.c:5
(lldb)
```

This new `jump` command will be available both in command-line lldb and in Xcode if you load it in your `~/.lldbinit` file -- you'll need to use the debugger console pane in Xcode to move the pc instead of moving the indicator in the editor window.

Comment: How did you test/debug this script?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the program counter (pc) in lldb using the lldb command `register write pc`.  But it's instruction based.

There's an excellent lldb/gdb comparison [here](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) that is useful as an lldb overview.